# SQLite Update Error in iOS, 'cannot commit - no transaction is active'

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I'm trying to update a SQLite database but I'm having trouble. Every time I click the button to update I get this error:

> cannot commit - no transaction is active

I can't see anything wrong with my code so I have no idea how to solve this problem.

```
-(BOOL)setup{
databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"words" ofType:@"sqlite"];
BOOL isSuccess = YES;
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ])
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        return  isSuccess;
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    else {
        isSuccess = NO;
        NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
    }
}

return isSuccess;
}


 - (NSMutableArray*) findWord:(int)ID
{
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"select Word, Category, Clue, Length, Solved from X where ID=\"%i\"",ID];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,
                           query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {

            NSString *solved = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:
                                (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];

            if ([solved intValue] == 0) {

                [resultArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", ID]];

                NSString *word = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                  (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                [resultArray addObject:word];

                NSString *cat = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                   (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                [resultArray addObject:cat];

                NSString *clue = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:
                               (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                [resultArray addObject:clue];

                NSString *length = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:
                                  (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
                [resultArray addObject:length];
            }
            else {

            }
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
            sqlite3_close(database);
            return resultArray;
        }
        else{
            return nil;
        }

    }
    sqlite3_reset(statement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
return nil;
}

- (void) findData{
NSMutableArray *m = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
m = [self findWord:arc4random() %10];
if (m == nil) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                          @"Data not found" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:
                          @"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"%@", [m objectAtIndex:1]);
}


}

-(IBAction)updateClick:(id)sender{

sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt;
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *sql = "update X Set Solved = 1 Where ID=2";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){

    }
}
char* errmsg;
sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);

if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt)){
    NSLog(@"Error while updating. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
sqlite3_close(database);

}
```

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the database from bundle itself. You can not update any of the bundle resource as they are signed by the certificate. If you want to edit the database, first copy it into Documents directory and then give the path of documents directory location and not of the bundle location. This will solve your problem.